# cronjob opening then IMMEDIATELY closing ssh tunnel

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, cron, tunnel

I'm trying to write a script that would open an SSH tunnel to a public-facing server. I've got everything written and working correctly, but the connection doesn't seem to be making it to my server. The logs say things like:

```
Jun 8 21:00:01 <hostname> CRON[xxxx]: session opened for user <user> by (uid=0)
Jun 8 21:00:01 <hostname> CRON[xxxx]: session closed for user <user>
```

Over and over, with 0-1 seconds in between. I want this connection to say open.... How can I keep this open?

My code looks like this for the cron (Yes, I know it's running every minute):

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/<user>/ssh
```

My code for the check-in is:

```
sshpass -p <password> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null <user>@<url> -p <port> -R222<random_number>:localhost:22
```

So, again, how can I keep this connection open? I have a mechanism to kill it at an appropriate time in another script, but unless I run the above command manually from the command line, cron immediately kills it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your crontab script.

1. The one that is causing the disconnections is the fact that the script needs not only execute permission, but also the suid bit set (*sudo chmod 4755 /pah/to/script*) **if** you are executing the shell script as root.
2. crontab environments are very different from users'. Hence it is always required to use *full paths* to commands:

   ```
   /usr/bin/sshpass -p <password> /usr/bin/ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null <user>@<url> -p <port> -R222<random_number>:localhost:22
   ```
3. You should add the flags *-t -t* to the *ssh* command (yes, twice) because this suppresses the error that a tty cannot be allocated.
4. While I am certain of the previous errors, there is one that *might* cause troubles, I am not sure and do not have the time to try it out: you have two *-p* flags in your command, and I am not sure they are correctly interpreted by the shell. If I were you, I would place the *ssh* command, with all its options, inside single or double quotes, just to try.

The previous objection and the use of an open password might be avoided if you were to use cryptographic keys, in which case you might add to your *.ssh/config* file the following lines:

```
   Host ShortName
             HostName The.Full.HostName.com
             User yourname
             Port your-non-standard-port
             IdentityFile /path/to/crypto/keyù
             IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and then the one-liner would become

```
  /usr/bin/ssh -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -R222<random_number>:localhost:22 ServerName
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Turns out it was the double '-t -t' that fixed it for me.